# get value from entry to be inside frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have frames generated automatically. these frames contain objects such as labels and only 1 entry.
I manage to identify the Entry with the following command:

> ```
>           for widget in FrameCalc.winfo_children():
>              print("widget.winfo_children()[4]", widget.winfo_children()[4])
> ```

which gives me this

> ```
>           .! toplevel.labels.! frame2.! entry
> ```

How can I get the value contained in the target Entry?
thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Please do not language-spam. Whatever this is, it is not `java`.

Comment: Neither `css`. Please elaborate and put an example on jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: What the point of the for loop as you have used `winfo_children[4]` directly to access the entry?

Comment: looks like dis is python and tkinter, try saying `entryname.get()` to fetch whats inside of your entry widget

Comment: PYthon Tkinter (sorry) - i find this solution Qt_HV_cible = widget.winfo_children()[4].get()

Comment: for widget in FrameCalc.winfo_children():
     print("Record_Data - widget         ", widget)
     Qt_HV_cible = widget.winfo_children()[4].get()
     print("Record_Data - Qt_HV_cible       ", Qt_HV_cible, type(Qt_HV_cible))

Comment: normaly i wnat use this      for z in range(0, len(frames)):
     print("Record_Data - frames -->       ", frames, len(frames)) -- the answer give me that [<tkinter.IntVar object at 0x02EBD7B0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x02EBD590>]  but i don't know how i can access Entry. if have solution is great.

Comment: have you tried `entryname.get()`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow community!

In your case, you can use any of `SrtingVar()`(holing string), `IntVar()`(holing integer), `DoubleVar()`(holding float) or `BooleanVar()`(holding boolean values) depending on your requirement and assign a `textvariable` to the `entry` widget. You can then append these variables into a list and use `.get()` method to retrieve it's contents when required. Here's an example, using a loop to create many entries with `StringVar()` and getting their values later.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def display(ent):
    global disp, var_list
    disp.set(var_list[ent].get())

var_list = []
for i in range (0, 5):
    var = StringVar()
    entry = Entry(root, textvariable = var)
    var_list.append(var)
    entry.pack()
    button = Button(root, text = "Show", command =  lambda ent = i: display(ent))
    button.pack()
    
disp = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable = disp)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for oyur answer. i know this process. that not answer of my prob!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for.

- use `isinstance()` to check for the widget type
- use `get()` to return the value

---

```
import tkinter as tk


#a dummy widget for example purposes
class DummyWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, t, e, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        tk.Label(self, text=t).grid(row=0, column=0)
        ent = tk.Entry(self)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        ent.insert(0, e)
    

#extend root
class App(tk.Tk):
    #application constants
    TITLE = 'Application'
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y = 800, 600, 50, 50

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        DummyWidget(self, "label 1", "entry 1").grid(row=0, column=0)
        DummyWidget(self, "label 2", "entry 2").grid(row=1, column=0)
        DummyWidget(self, "label 3", "entry 3").grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        #this is the answer portion of the example
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            for i, subwidget in enumerate(widget.winfo_children()):
                if isinstance(subwidget, tk.Entry):
                    print(f'child {i} of widget', subwidget.get())


#properly initialize your app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}+{App.X}+{App.Y}')
    #app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

This concept could also be turned into a utility, so you have a dynamic system of finding whatever you want, starting from wherever you want. I would definitely consider this preferable to rewriting the above multi-dimensional loop (that stops at grandchildren) every time you need to find specific instance types.

```
import tkinter as tk
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type


#a dummy widget for example purposes
class DummyWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, t, e, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        tk.Label(self, text=t).grid(row=0, column=0)
        ent = tk.Entry(self)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
        ent.insert(0, e)
        
 
#to illustrate inheritance        
class DummyEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, text, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.insert(0, text)
   
 
#used in Utils.GetInstancesAsDataFrom(...) to store individual widget data
@dataclass
class WidgetData_dc:
    type:       Type
    parent:     tk.Widget
    childindex: int
    path:       str
    

class Utils:
    """ GetInstancesFrom
    deep search of every child, grandchild, etc.. for a specific widget type
    @start ~ parent widget to start the search from
    @wtype ~ the type of widget to find
    @inst  ~ used internally to pass the dictionary to this method's internal calls of itself
    returns a dictionary of all found instances 
    """
    @staticmethod
    def GetInstancesFrom(start, wtype, inst=None):
        instances = dict() if inst is None else inst
        for widget in start.winfo_children():
            if isinstance(widget, wtype):
                instances[f'{widget}'] = widget
            Utils.GetInstancesFrom(widget, wtype, instances)

        return instances
        
    """ GetInstancesAsDataFrom
    deep search of every child, grandchild, etc.. for a specific widget type
    @start ~ parent widget to start the search from
    @wtype ~ the type of widget to find
    @inst  ~ used internally to pass the dictionary to this method's internal calls of itself
    returns a dictionary of all found instances 
    """
    @staticmethod
    def GetInstancesAsDataFrom(start, wtype, inst=None):
        instances = dict() if inst is None else inst
        for i, widget in enumerate(start.winfo_children()):
            if isinstance(widget, wtype):
                instances[widget] = WidgetData_dc(type(widget), start, i, f'{widget}')
            Utils.GetInstancesAsDataFrom(widget, wtype, instances)

        return instances                  


#extend root
class App(tk.Tk):
    #application constants
    TITLE = 'Application'
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y = 800, 600, 50, 50

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        #a bunch of junk instances for example purposes
        DummyWidget(self, "label 1", "entry 1").grid(column=0)
        DummyWidget(self, "label 2", "entry 2").grid(column=0)
        DummyWidget(self, "label 3", "entry 3").grid(column=0)
        DummyEntry(self, text='entry 4').grid(column=0) #this extends tk.Entry so it qualifies as a tk.Entry
        
        #answer portion of the example
        for path, widget in Utils.GetInstancesFrom(self, tk.Entry).items():
            print(f'{path}: {widget.get()}')
            
        print('') #skip a line
            
        #alternate implementation
        for widget, data in Utils.GetInstancesAsDataFrom(self, tk.Entry).items():
            print(f'{data.parent}[{data.childindex}]:{data.type} has value "{widget.get()}"')


#properly initialize your app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}+{App.X}+{App.Y}')
    #app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: console output]